# "Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent" when calling session_start() first in file

Tags: php, session, utf-8

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['start']=1;

   echo $_SESSION['start'];
?>
```

Output in FF:

> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cookie - headers already sent
>   by (output started at .../test.php:1)
>   in.../test.php on line 10
>
> Warning: session_start()
>   [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   .../test.php:1) in.../test.php on line
>   10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have saved your file in UTF-8 format, be sure to check if it is **UTF-8 without BOM**.

Comment: Good call. I bet you're right. I first learned about the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) when I opened a script in nano and it had a strange character at the beginning.

Comment: I resaved my file in UTF-8 no BOM but it didnt solve it. I remember I had this prob before and it sure sound like it. Do I have to change anything else or should the resave solve it? How about doctype, mysql connection etc? Or is it simply something else?

Comment: resaving solved it! Still, do I need to change anything else or does the utf8 no bom only apply to the encoding the file is saved as?

Comment: Happy to hear it solved it. If you want to use UTF-8, be sure to apply it to META content-type, php header Content-type, MySQL connection, collation in your database and tables (and the encoding of your PHP files if you want to use UTF-8 constants). And anything I can't think of when I'm drunk.

Comment: This one saved my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

Did you include this file from any other file? If so, then did those files echo/output anything?

The HTTP header that includes cookies must be outputted before the body (the HTML, usually).

Answer (score 0):

Along with rFactor's response, check that you do not have any white space at the top of the PHP file (e.g. a space or a period).

Comment: white space checked before posting

Comment: @Joseph, OK then, I'll leave this answer here anyways just incase someone comes across it in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Changed encoding from UTF8 to ANSI, then saved the file and the error went away.